# QListWidget does not resize itself

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

In the following code, I'm hiding non-selected items in a `QListWidget`. (`self.field` is an
instance of `QListWidget`).

```
# Make selected items visible and other items hidden:
for i in range(self.field.count()):
   self.field.item(i).setHidden(not self.field.item(i).isSelected())
```

When I hide non-selected items, they are essentially whited out, i.e., the space does not close up (see below).  Is there any way to close up the whitespace?

[image: Expanded]

[image: Collapsed]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a list widget with a dynamic height. This is achieved by subclassing `QListWidget` and overriding `viewportSizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint`. The size adjust policy is set to `AdjustToContents` so that the list widget will update its size when its contents have changed. The horizontal scroll bar is set to `ScrollBarAlwaysOff` to avoid the extra vertical space added at the bottom of the list widget that is reserved for the horizontal scroll bar if it were to be shown.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class ListWidget(QtWidgets.QListWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

    def minimumSizeHint(self) -> QtCore.QSize:
        return QtCore.QSize(-1, -1)

    def viewportSizeHint(self) -> QtCore.QSize:
        if self.model().rowCount() == 0:
            return QtCore.QSize(self.width(), 0)
        height = sum(self.sizeHintForRow(i) for i in range(self.count()) if not self.item(i).isHidden())
        width = super().viewportSizeHint().width()
        return QtCore.QSize(width, height)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # create and populate ListWidget instance
        self.list_widget = ListWidget()
        self.list_widget.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QListWidget.MultiSelection)
        self.list_widget.addItems('Aardvark Bear Cat Donkey Echidna Ferret Goose'.split())

        # setup rest of gui
        self.select_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Select')
        self.clear_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Clear selection')

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Choose your mascots'))
        vlayout.addWidget(self.list_widget)

        # stretch added to layout to accommodate for varying height of list widget
        vlayout.addStretch(1)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.select_button)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.clear_button)
        self.select_button.setDefault(True)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)

        self.select_button.clicked.connect(self.select)
        self.clear_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_selection)

    def select(self):
        for i in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            self.list_widget.item(i).setHidden(not self.list_widget.item(i).isSelected())

    def clear_selection(self):
        self.list_widget.clearSelection()
        for i in range(self.list_widget.count()):
            self.list_widget.item(i).setHidden(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    app.exec()
```

Screenshot:

[image: original list widget]
[image: resized list widget]